# How to find out what tables/views/synonyms are used in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dependencies

Through Oracle queries is it possible to find out which views/synonyms/tables a stored procedure use?

In PL/SQL Developer if you collapse out a stored procedure it will show "References" which shows all the tables/views/synonyms that the stored procedure uses.

I am trying to implement this functionality into a script which will come in handy.

Wondering if anyone knows a script that will fetch me all the synonyms/views/tables that a stored procedure uses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information you are looking for is in the user_dependencies/all_dependencies view.

Comment: Except where dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE / DBMS_SQL) is used.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Rene is correct however I believe it needs additional explanation. When selecting from `all_dependencies` you might run query like one below that should give you all the objects that are referencing your SP.

```
SELECT *
FROM all_dependencies
WHERE "REFERENCED_NAME" = 'vcustomeraddresses';
```

You might be surprised when it will come back empty-handed.
This is because oracle is CASE SENSITIVE. What this means is that you have [to ether disable case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle) (if version of oracle you are using is above 10g r2)

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
```

or `upper` both sides when comparing

```
SELECT *
FROM all_dependencies
WHERE upper("REFERENCED_NAME") = upper('vcustomeraddresses');
```

Hope this saves you some time and frustration.