# In Ormlite, write case insensitive query

Tags: ormlite

In Ormlite, is it possible to make case-insensitive query without writing the actual SQL?

For example, if I am looking for

column name - "AccountName"
and query on the column, I would like to get results for all "Finance", "fInance", "FINANCE", etc. if I do search on "finance".

I was wondering if there's a functional support for this or if I need to write a SQL for it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am answering my own question, but the following seems to work.

```
newDao.query(newDao.queryBuilder().where().like("nameColumn", "finance")
    .prepare())
```

Above seems to return all 
"finance", "Finance", "FINANCE" or any other variations of it.

Comment: Of course, using Like instead of equal *may* prevent the indexes to be used. If performance issues arise, check your query plan.

Answer (score 1):

Right now (May 2011) there is no mechanism to do this with ORMLite except for writing the actual SQL and using the `queryRaw()` and other raw methods.

In many databases, MySQL for example, [case insensitivity looks to be the default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).  But this is not the case with [Postgresql](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/postgresql/do-case-insensitive-searching-with-postgresql) nor [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/make-oracle-sql-like-query-case-insensitive).

A quick look around at the various database implementations shows that there is not a very easy and portable way to do this.  Am I wrong?