# Oracle select query with substr

Tags: oracle, select, oracle10g, substr

I have a table which looks like:

```
DAYDATE     TIMEOFDAY   USERID
18-JUL-12   Afternoon   mistu4u
18-JUL-12   Noon        mistu4u
20-JUL-12   Noon        mistu4u
21-JUL-12   Afternoon   mistu4u
11-SEP-12   Afternoon   rimo
06-AUG-12   Noon        rimo
14-JUN-12   Noon        mistu4u
```

Now I want to fetch those values for mistu4u whose daydate's month is 'jul'.I tried like

```
select * from mealdb where userid='mistu4u' and substr(daydate,4,3)='jul';
```

But it is giving 'no data found'.

Comment: Also anybody can suggest if the same can be acheived through "LIKE" keyword!!

Comment: What is the datatype of `DAYDATE`?  You want July of any year?

Comment: datatype of daydate is varchar2

Comment: I just resolved it.My installation is case sensitive.That is what was creating problem.Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your install case sensitive?   Does this SQL work?

```
select * from mealdb where userid='mistu4u' and substr(daydate,4,3)='JUL';
```

Comment: OMG!!It is!!It just worked!!But sure I want to make it case insensitive.@ProfessionalAmateur can you tell me how to make it so?Also can you suggest how to write it with "LIKE".

Comment: @Subir Adhikari - It can be done.  Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/make-oracle-sql-like-query-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM   mealdb
WHERE  userid = 'mistu4u'
AND    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(daydate,'MM')) = 7
;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
TRUNC(daydate, 'MONTH') = '01-JULY-2012'
```

Be careful if you have any indexes on the daydate column. The substr will render it useless. Perhaps, consider using a BETWEEN instead.

Also, most of the solutions will pick up all records in *any* year for the month of July.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
select * from mealdb where userid='mistu4u' and daydate like '%JUL%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from mealdb
where userid='mistu4u'
and upper(daydate) LIKE '%JUL%';
```