# Sorting order issue in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When I use below query

```
select model from client_source order by model;
```

the resulting data is in this order

```
model
______
1234
4g
default
unknown
default1
ipad
iphone simulator
ipod touch
iphone
ipod
test
```

but I want the sorting in below order

```
model
________

1234
4g
default
default1
ipad
iphone
iphone simulator
ipod
ipod touch
test
unknown
```

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate: case-insensitive **searching** and **sorting** are different (even if some parameters play a role in both cases)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your [`NLS_SORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams153.htm#REFRN10127) parameter is `BINARY`. In `BINARY` sort, the strings are sorted as their binary expression, which means that the uppercase letters will be coming before the lowercase letters:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort=binary;

Session altered

SQL> select model from client_source order by model;

MODEL
--------------------
1234
4g
Default
Unknown
default1
ipad
iphone
iphone simulator
ipod
ipod touch
test
```

You can change this behaviour with different `NLS_SORT` values. Use a [value of `NLS_SORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i637232) with the `_CI` suffix to make it case-insensitive:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort=latin_ci;

Session altered

SQL> select model from client_source order by model;

MODEL
--------------------
Default
default1
ipad
iphone
iphone simulator
ipod
ipod touch
test
Unknown
1234
4g
```

You can move the digits at the front with a `CASE`:

```
SQL> SELECT model
  2    FROM client_source
  3   ORDER BY CASE WHEN regexp_like(model, '^[[:digit:]]')
  4                    THEN 0
  5                    ELSE 1
  6            END,
  7            model;

MODEL
--------------------
1234
4g
Default
default1
ipad
iphone
iphone simulator
ipod
ipod touch
test
Unknown
```

Additionally, you can use the [`NLSSORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm#SQLRF00678) function to modify the sorting preference of a single query:

```
select model from client_source order by NLSSORT(model, 'NLS_SORT = LATIN_CI');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!.

I am sorry, the values I gave was not correct. Here are the correct values.

Model
______
1234
4G
DEFAULT
Unknown
default1
iPad
iPhone Simulator
iPod touch
iphone
ipod
test

I want the sort order like below.

Model
________
1234
4G
DEFAULT
default1
iPad
iPhone Simulator
iphone
ipod
test
Unknown.

words with same type should be grouped like

iPhone Simulator
iphone


the above two rows are related to iphone, so they should be one below the other

Comment: I think you want case-insensitive sort, see my updated answer.

Comment: Rather than relying on a specific language maintaining a case-insensitive sort wouldn't it be better to actually use a NLS_SORT parameter that explicitly states this, BINARY_CI for instance, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle/