# PDO like Query is Case Sensitive

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

i don't get the appropriate results from LIKE search using PDO because PDO search is case sensitive, i want case insensitive.

I have this query, but it returns only data which fully matches if there is Alphabet `a` small in database, the i don't get result if i search with capital alphabet `A`.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ROOM, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME, CONFIRMATION_NO, DEPARTURE, PWD FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE GUEST_FIRST_NAME LIKE ? OR GUEST_NAME LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%','%'.$searchFilter.'%' ));
```

is there anyway to fix this query to make it case insensitive?

im using oracle 11g Xpress Edition database.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle

Comment: @Mr.Smith PDO is not a DBMS. PDO is an abstraction layer that sits between PHP and a database using one of a number of drivers for various DBMSes such as MySQL, MSSQL, and *Oracle* to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually something like the following works

```
…WHERE LOWER(GUEST_FIRST_NAME) LIKE ? OR LOWER(GUEST_NAME LIKE) ?
$stmt->execute(array('%'.strtolower($searchFilter).'%','%'.strtolower($searchFilter).'%' ));
```

Comment: The last bracket in line 1 of your code is displaced :)