# Oracle: how to "unalter" a session parameter?

Tags: oracle

I'm doing a case-insensitive query with

```
alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
```

Is there a way to easily capture the session state prior to altering it so that I can restore the session to its original state?

Comment: Did you try a query on `v$parameter2` (see https://community.oracle.com/message/3577293)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the current values using:

```
select * 
from nls_session_parameters;
```

before you change your session. To restore it, you just use the saved values.

I am not aware of any statement that resets the session parameters to the default value.

Comment: This is the best way to do it as far as I know.  But it seems like there *should* be a better way.  For example, the `reset` syntax is undocumented for `session` but does appear to work.  For example, `alter session reset nls_sort;` will reset it.  But it will reset it to the *Oracle* default, not the previous *system* default.

Answer (score 0):

The NLS parameters are exposed through a series of views, starting with NLS_.  In your case you need  [NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5149.htm#REFRN29032).  There are equivalent views for Instance and Database.

This is neater than using [v$parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2087.htm#REFRN30176), although that view does allow us to tell whether a paarmeter is changed from the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a given session parameter by:

```
SELECT value
FROM   nls_session_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_SORT'; -- replace NLS_SORT with parameter of your choice
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14787642/1461424) demonstrates other means of doing a case insensitive search.

1. Using `UPPER()`/`LOWER()` functions with a [function based index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1161).
2. Regular expressions: [`REGEXP_LIKE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the **parameter values** initially :

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER NLS_SORT;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
nls_sort                             string      BINARY

SQL> SHOW PARAMETER NLS_COMP;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
nls_comp                             string      BINARY
```

And then set the **session parameter** accordingly :

```
SQL> alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';

Session altered

SQL> alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_CI';

Session altered
```

In **PL/SQL**, you can do the following to fetch the parameter value and store it in **session variable** :

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    VAR_NLS_SORT VARCHAR2(10);
  3    var_nls_comp VARCHAR2(10);
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT VALUE
  6       INTO VAR_NLS_SORT
  7      FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
  8     WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_SORT';
  9    SELECT VALUE
 10       INTO VAR_NLS_COMP
 11      FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
 12     WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_COMP';
 13    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NLS_SORT = '||VAR_NLS_SORT);
 14    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NLS_COMP = '||VAR_NLS_COMP);
 15  END;
 16  /
NLS_SORT = BINARY
NLS_COMP = BINARY

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

For more information, you can have a look at [Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/)