# like operator not working in oracle database

Tags: php, jquery, oracle, oracle10g, sql-like

I am trying to fetch data from oracle database onkeyup function. Here is my HTML code.

```
    <form name="filter_name"action="jqry.php" method="post">
       <input class="name" name="name" type="text" id="name">
       <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

And here is my jquery code:

```
    $(function(){
        $("#name").keyup(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name;
         if(name!='') {
            $.ajax({ 
               type: "POST",
               url: "connectdb.php",
               data: dataString,
               cache: false,
               success: function(html) {
                  alert(html);
               }
             });
            }
            return false;
          });
        });
```

Initially I have written the query as below in `connectdb.php`

```
    <?php          
       $text = $_POST['name']; 
       // I have given db connections here
       $query="SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES";
       $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query); 
       oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT); 
       echo "<table border='1'>\n";
       while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) { 
         echo "<tr>\n";     
         foreach ($row as $item) {         
              echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";     
            }
           echo "</tr>\n";
         }
      echo "</table>\n";
      oci_free_statement($stid);
      oci_close($conn);
     ?>
```

For this I am getting the output correctly in the alert as

```
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>XYZ</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>PQR</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

But when I try to match the name with POST variable i.e, `$text`, that I get from onkeyup using `LIKE`operator, I am getting empty output though they are name matching the variable. I am not able to understand why the query is failed when I use the below query.

```
    $query = "SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE NAME LIKE '%".$text."%'";
```

example when I type `a` in the input box with `id="name"`, the output I am getting in alert is as below. That is I am getting zero results.

```
    <table border="1">
    </table>
```

For reference here is my database table structure:

```
    |  EMP ID  |  EMP_NAME  |
    |    1     |    ABC     |
    |    2     |    XYZ     |
    |    3     |    PQR     |
```

Please anyone help me that why I am getting empty results when I use LIKE operator

Comment: this `'%".$text."%'` might give you strange output, i would change it to `'%$text%'`

Comment: Print your query -> echo $query; what query is generated?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com When I have tried echo $query; die(); and typed a letter a in the input box, I got the alert as SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE NAME LIKE '%a%'

Comment: Yes , so query is correct , Type `A` in CAPS ,search will work. Check my answer.

Comment: See if this helps https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/

Comment: Shouln't it be ...WHERE **EMP_NAME** LIKE...?

Comment: Be aware of the SQL injection vulnerability in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
"...WHERE LOWER(NAME) like lower('%".$text."%')...."
```

**Reason:**

By default oracle does case `Sensitive` search . So convert your string to lower and convert db value also to lower and then compare.

Refer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786923/like-condition-case-insensitive-in-oracle-sql)**