# Oracle regular expression using hyphen in pattern

Tags: oracle11g

Why is this query returning the value 4 (I expected 0)?

```
select  regexp_instr ('123abc','[A-Z]')
from dual;
```

I think `[]` should indicate a character list, and A-Z includes all upper letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [affected by your session's NLS_SORT setting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG302), and you will get a result of 4 if you have case-insensitive sorting enabled:

```
alter session set nls_sort=binary;
select  regexp_instr ('123abc','[A-Z]')
from dual;

REGEXP_INSTR('123ABC','[A-Z]')
------------------------------
                             0

alter session set nls_sort=binary_ci;
select  regexp_instr ('123abc','[A-Z]')
from dual;

REGEXP_INSTR('123ABC','[A-Z]')
------------------------------
                             4
```

You can read more [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005); and you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle#5391234) useful too.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and links!