# Insensitive on compounds name with uppercase

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine

I got some problems with a request with Doctrine.

I do a `findOneByFieldName` on my entity which is supposed to retrieves me an object.

I want to `findOneByNameSurname` (`NameSurname` is a string) with a parameter which contains for example *'BEART Jean-Francois'*.

What I want is that doctrine retrieves me the user *BEART Jean-Francois*, if only *BEART Jean-Francois* exists in the table. Nevertheless, if I give to doctrine *'BEART Jean-francois'* with an `f` lowercase, doctrine still retrieves me the user holding the *'BEART Jean-Francois'* field  with the `F` uppercase.

What I want is that doctrine should be sensitive with the whole string, I mean that it should not squizze the duplicate name, even if, for real its not a duplicate name as it is written differently (upper case on the f letter).

I tried to run an SQL request directly in `SqlDeveloper` to test if Oracle makes the difference with and without the `f` lower or uppercase in *'Jean-Francois'*, and it DOES.

So what am I missing ? How can I say to doctrine, if you got an `f` lowercase in the string parameter I give you, and you only find a `F` uppercase in DB, please don't retrieve me anything, its not a match ...

Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: create your own repository function - read documentation first: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

Comment: You shouldn't write the tags in your tittle; also see how to make your question clearer. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problems in my oracle Listener ....

I had that :

```
private static $_SQL_SET_SORT = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=Latin_AI";
private static $_SQL_SET_COMP = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC";
```

Changed it to that and now doctrine is sensitive :

```
 private static $_SQL_SET_SORT = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI";
  private static $_SQL_SET_COMP = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=BINARY";
```

See this post for more info :

[Case insensitive searching in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle)