# Is value on the list of values? (Oracle SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Below works for SQL Server and MySQL, but how to modify it to work as proper Oracle query:

```
SELECT city FROM station WHERE LEFT(city, 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

I'm stuck at:

```
SELECT city FROM station WHERE SUBSTR(city,1, 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: list all cities with names starting for 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' or 'u'

Comment: What's the problem you have with the query?

Comment: ok, SQL Server and MySQL don't take into account if letters is capital or not

Comment: You may want to look at [Case insensitive searching in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is perfectly OK provided that the cities you are interested in start with lowercase letters. If that's not the case you may want to use LOWER function:

```
SELECT city FROM station WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(city,1, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a version that works in all three databases you can use `like`:

```
SELECT s.city
FROM station s
WHERE LOWER(s.city) LIKE 'a%' OR
      LOWER(s.city) LIKE 'e%' OR
      LOWER(s.city) LIKE 'i%' OR
      LOWER(s.city) LIKE 'o%' OR
      LOWER(s.city) LIKE 'u%';
```