# Oracle SQL Query Displaying Empty Results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a simple query to display the names of columns in my table.

This is the SQL I used:

```
select column_name from cols where table_name='StudentInfo';
```

For some reason, this query results in an empty result table even though my StudentInfo table does indeed have columns.

Comment: Try `select distinct table_name from cols` and check if `"StudentInfo"` shines up that way. Probably table names are stored in capital letters or in any other slightly different way.

Comment: Boom. You just  solved my problem. Any idea why oracle has such sharp case sensitivity?

Comment: will definitely give an upvote and a check mark for that one. Thank you! Really appreciate it

Comment: see edited answer concerning case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table names might be stored in capital letters such that a condition `table_name='StudentInfo'` fails. Note that Oracle (and most other RDBMS I know) compare strings in a case sensitive manner. For a case insensitive comparison, use `UPPER` (or `LOWER`) on both arguments. So the following query should work safely:

```
select column_name from cols where upper(table_name)=upper('StudentInfo')
```

There are other ways of turning string comparison into case insensitive, like altering session parameters `NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT` (cf., for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5391234/2630032 and upvote this reference if applicable). By using `UPPER`, however, you make your query independent of such settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for this:

```
select column_name from cols where lower(table_name) like '%studentinfo%'
```

Comment: @StephanLechner Yes! It would display all records containg the string 'studentinfo'. But if we only want records which has the required sign then % should be removed from the query.

Comment: Note that `like` is also case sensitive (depending on settings). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5391234/2630032