# SQL for Mixed Case filter

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was just wondering how you would search for any mix of case. For instance, I want to find all employees with the last name 'davies', but I want to be able to find any mix of case such as 'DavIes' or 'DAVies'. This is what I've tried.

```
SELECT LAST_NAME

FROM EMPLOYEES

WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID

FROM EMPLOYEES

WHERE LAST_NAME = '[Dd][Aa][Vv][Ii][Ee][Ss]');
```

Comment: I'd write a function based index which UPPER or LOWERs the name.  This way the database can use the function based index to search instead of just the last_name.  [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS257)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive searching in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UPPER` or `LOWER` function and `IN`

```
SELECT LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN (
   SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   WHERE UPPER(LAST_NAME) = 'DAVIES'
);
```

Unfortunately it invalidates the index use.

Comment: why do you need IN? you are looking for last_name from Employees

Comment: @maSTAShuFu yes, it is wierd. I did not noticed that he is querying the same table in the subquery. I wrongly assumed that it must be a different table.

Answer (score 1):

Using **UPPER**

```
SELECT *
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   WHERE UPPER(LAST_NAME) = 'DAVIES'
```