# Oracle REGEXP_INSTR() and "a-z" character range doesn't match as expected

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to use `REGEXP_INSTR()` within an oracle database to check for lower/uppercase characters. I'm aware of `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` POSIX character classes, but I went with `a-z` that gives me really weird results I don't understand. Can someone explain this?

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('abc','[A-Z]',1,1,0,'c') FROM DUAL
-- Got 2, expected 0

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('zyx','[A-Z]',1,1,0,'c') FROM DUAL
-- Got 1, expected 0

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('ABC','[a-z]',1,1,0,'c') FROM DUAL
-- Got 1, expected 0

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('ZYX','[a-z]',1,1,0,'c') FROM DUAL
-- Got 2, expected 0

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('a3','[A-F0-9]',1,1,0,'c') FROM DUAL
-- Got 2, expected 2

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('b3','[A-F0-9]',1,1,0,'c') FROM DUAL
-- Got 1, expected 2

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('b3','[A-F0-9]') FROM DUAL
-- Got 1, expected 1 or 2

SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('a3','[A-F0-9]') FROM DUAL
-- Got 2, expected same as above
```

Comment: *`'c': Turn on case sensitive matching.`* So `REGEXP_INSTR('zyx','[A-Z]',1,1,0,'c')` will match `z`, for example, and you can't expect `0`. Mind that *The first character in the string has position 1.* See https://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html

Comment: Yes, 'c' turns on case sensitive matching. 'z' is lowercase. I expect '[A-Z]' to match uppercase characters from A to Z. Why would it match z?

Comment: Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5391234/3832970), check if  `NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT` session parameters interfere with regex case sensitive matching.

Comment: Lets assume `c` made `[A-Z]` equal to `[A-Za-z]`, which I doubt, because that would be case-IN-sensitive, why wouldn't then the first query return `1`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think is not quite correct. why is the result in the first example then 2 and not 1?

Comment: I understand that `NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT` may have an impact here regarding case sensitivity. What I really don't understand at all are the last two queries. How on earth can they give different results? If `b` matches `A-F`, why wouldn't `a`?

Comment: okay wait, it makes sense if the order is `aAbBcC` and `A-F` actually expands to `AbBcCdDeEfF` and `a-f` expands to `aAbBcCdDeEf`... wow

Comment: Looks like the collation effect. Try setting `NLS_SORT` as `BINARY`

Comment: @xsrf if you set `NLS_SORT = binary` you will get your expected result

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the behavior is the collation rules. See the [`NLS_SORT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams145.htm#REFRN10127):

> - If the value is BINARY, then the collating sequence for ORDER BY queries is based on the numeric value of characters (a binary sort that requires less system overhead).
> - If the value is a named linguistic sort, sorting is based on the order of the defined linguistic sort. Most (but not all) languages supported by the NLS_LANGUAGE parameter also support a linguistic sort with the same name.

Set the `NLS_SORT` to `BINARY` so that the `[A-Z]` could be parsed in the same order as in the ASCII table,

```
alter session set nls_sort = 'BINARY'
```

Then, you will get consistent results.

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/IAXJA14149).

Answer (score -1):

Okay, the answer that [`NLS_SORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams145.htm#REFRN10127) causes this behavior is correct, but I don't think it explains it in an understandable way. None of the documentation I found actually does that...

You have to imagine that the character ranges defined by `[a-z]` are actually derived from a single substring of all possible characters which are sorted depending on `NLS_SORT`.

Lets assume the whole alphabet is just alphanumerical characters. Sorted by `BINARY` this results in a base string like `0123456789abcdefgh...xyzABCDE...XYZ`.
Derived from this, `[0-6]` expands to `[0123456]`, `[a-f]` to `[abcdef]`, `[5-b]` to `[56789ab]` etc.

Sorted by a `linguistic_definition` however results in a different base string, like `0123456789aAbBcCdDeF...xXyYzZ`.
Derived from this, `[0-6]` still expands to `[0123456]`, but `[a-f]` now expands to `[aAbBcCdDeEf]` and `[5-b]` to `[56789aAb]` etc...

This is why `a` did not match `[A-Z]`, but `b` did. `[A-Z]` actually expands to `[AbBcC...yYzZ]` which includes `z` but not `a`.

In reality `[A-Z]` might even contain more characters, like `[aAàáâÀÁÂ...]` etc.