# Optimize query to work for Lower Case and Upper Case

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, soap

I want to optimize my query to return result either user insert `New York` or `NEW YORK` or `new york`
I have around 10000 record  in `db` and some record start with upper later some with lower latter, and my query doesnt return result if I insert like `New York`.

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string GetAkontasByMjesto(string Mjesto)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=test-1:1521/fba;USER ID=test;PASSWORD=test");
            OracleDataAdapter dr = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from AKONTAS where MJESTO='" + Mjesto + "'", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add("AKONTAS");
            dr.Fill(ds, "AKONTAS");
            DataTable tt = ds.Tables[0];
            return ds.GetXml();
        }
```

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: The real problem is the string concatenation that allows SQL injection attacks and conversion errors. What would happen if `Mjesto` contained `';drop table AKONTAS;//` ?

Comment: The We will have a big problem.

Comment: In any case the case sensitivity of queries depends on the *column's* collation. Typically, databases use case-insensitive collations and that query should return the results you want, no matter the casing. If it doesn't, check what's happening - did someone create the table with a case-sensitive collation? Why? You should probably change it to be case-insensitive, you'll have to change the collation to a case-insensitive one

Comment: Yes, I know check database and table and since I am not sys admin I can not change anything to database and table. 
However thank you for you advise.

Comment: Collation *matters a lot* because it affects indexes too. If you use `UPPER` on the field, you'll prevent the server from using any indexes on `MJESTO` to speed up the query and the server will have to scan the entire database. The query will be slow even for 10K rows

Comment: Doesnt matter. Speed in my case is not so important. I only care about data :)

Comment: Is this not a duplicat of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle | You basically just want to make it case-insensitive, right?

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle

Comment: @Xerrox not you maybe, but what about outer people's code that has to wait because your code is scanning the entire table? Never mind the DBAs that see the IO spikes. In any case, Dmitry Bychenko explained in a comment that you can create an index on a function in Oracle. In that case you could use `UPPER(MJESTO)` without a performance penalty. Adding an index is a small change and probably easier to get accepted.

Comment: @TheBetpet Jinx! Even down to the same second :D

Comment: I know, spooky right? XD

Comment: The duplicate offers two great solutions to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can lower both of Mjesto(parameter name) and MJESTO(column name)

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetAkontasByMjesto(string Mjesto)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=test-1:1521/fba;USER ID=test;PASSWORD=test");
    OracleDataAdapter dr = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from AKONTAS where lower(MJESTO) ='" + Mjesto.ToLower() + "'", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add("AKONTAS");
    dr.Fill(ds, "AKONTAS");
    DataTable tt = ds.Tables[0];
    return ds.GetXml();
}
```

Comment: This will prevent the server from using any indexes. The query will have to scan the entire table. That's not a viable solution for production systems

Comment: *Counter example*: `Mjesto = "cap d'antibes"`; do not *hard code* apostrophes

Comment: Will `toLower()` work with turquish "I" ? (rethorical question)

Comment: @Fildor the Turkish `i`! Ouch!

Comment: @Fildor IDK I can't check now this cause of my job maybe later :(

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, yes. Once you ran into it, you'll _always_ remember.

Comment: @Fildor it's a [well known problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) that explains why just using UPPER or LOWER is *not* enough

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use UPPER

For example:

```
select * 
from yourtable 
where upper(column) = upper('nEw York');
```

Comment: This will prevent the server from using any indexes. The query will have to scan the entire table. That's not a viable solution for production systems

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: in case of *Oracle* we can build index on *function*, in this case `Upper(column)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko or indexed computed columns in other databases. That's a viable idea if the OP can modify the database, and probably easier to get through  a DBA than changing the collation