# SQL nested query returning incorrect records (Toad 13 for Oracle)

Tags: sql, r, toad, subquery

This code works through R in R Studio but when translating the second part into SQL, I've run into many problems.

```
(SELECT L.DATE,
       UPPER(L.USERNAME),
       L.ID,
       L.BUSINESS
FROM LOGS L
WHERE L.APPLICATION = 'A'
AND L.BUSINESS IN ('X','Y','Z')
AND L.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2/1/2019    23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

This returns the desired amount of records. When I want to add the following conditions, I get the incorrect amount of records.

```
AND L.USERNAME IN (SELECT U.USERNAME FROM USERS U WHERE U.TEAM='DATA')
```

I've tried adding this condition in various ways but the syntax either prevents execution or it returns the wrong amount of records. I'm looking for help as to how to properly nest this query.

For reference, the second statement was written like this in R where ADD is the assignment for the first statement (R dataframe):

```
DATA<-USERS%>%filter(TEAM=='DATA')
DATA[,1]<-toupper(DATA[,1])
ADD[,2]<-toupper(ADD[,2])
DATA_FINAL<-ADD%>%filter(USERNAME %in% DATA$USERNAME)
```

I've been writing this manually in the editor without Toad's query builder as I find it cumbersome. Execution has been done in Toad Script Runner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Case sensitivity? `AND UPPER(L.USERNAME) IN (SELECT UPPER(U.USERNAME) FROM USERS U WHERE U.TEAM='DATA')`

Comment: Wow what an oversight. You are correct! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is most likely a case-senitivity:

```
SELECT L.DATE,
       UPPER(L.USERNAME),
       L.ID,
       L.BUSINESS
FROM LOGS L
WHERE L.APPLICATION = 'A'
AND L.BUSINESS IN ('X','Y','Z')
AND L.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
               AND TO_DATE('2/1/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
AND UPPER(L.USERNAME) IN (SELECT UPPER(U.USERNAME) FROM USERS U WHERE U.TEAM='DATA') 
    -- this expression is non-SARGable(without function index)!
```

Related article [Case insensitive searching in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810794/5070879)