# Pattern Matching with multiple possibilities sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to match a string against one of three possible entries. Right now I have

```
select * from table x 
where column1 like '%INSERT%' 
or column1 like '%Insert%' 
or column1 like '%insert%';
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, maybe using 'in' and 'like' in conjunction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle

Comment: Are the three possible entries always upper/lower/mixed case variations of the same text? If the three strings are `''%INSERT%'`, `%'Insert%'` and `'%Kittens!%'`, that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12.2 (`CI` is case-insensitive, `AI` is accent-insensitive as well as case-insensitive):

```
where column1 collate binary_ci like '%insert%'
```

Earlier

```
where regexp_like(column1, 'insert', 'i')
```

or

```
where upper(column1) like '%INSERT%'
```

Documentation: [Oracle Database 19c Linguistic Sorting and Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html)