# Case insensitive where-in SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a WHERE-IN query (using Oracle) that is case insensitive. I've tried this way:

`select user from users where lower(user) in lower('userNaMe1', 'useRNAmE2');`

but I get *ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments*

The list is dynamically generated in my Spring app. That's why I can't add lower() to every single list's value.
Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

`lower()` takes a single argument, so you can use:

```
where lower(user) in (lower('userNaMe1'), lower('useRNAmE2'))
```

You could also express this using regular expressions (`regexp_like()` accepts a case sensitivity argument) if you prefer:

```
where regexp_like(user, '^(userNaMe1|useRNAmE2)$', 'i')
```

Comment: The list is dynamically generated in my Spring app. That's why I can't add lower() to every single list's value.

Comment: But you can save your List in a Variable and add LOWER to every single String or you can use JPA instead of SQL Query.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to find and use JPA method findByUserInIgnoreCase(List<String> users)

Answer (score 0):

There is another more drastic approach, and is to make your session or your searching in the database case insensitive.

You can find how to do it in this answer:

[Case insensitive searching in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle)